# Send SMS using Skype from PHP

Tags: php, sms, skype

Is there a real skype api sms gateway ? I want to develop a very light client for Skype in php.

I have found Skype4com but it is not very useful since the user can't send an sms with his username/password.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339951/send-sms-with-skype-using-php

Comment: I already know this post, but it is not the same. I want to make a php that use the username of my customers, not mine.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forget skype api, send the sms to directly to the sms email address of the phone, most/all carriars provide 2125551212@cingularme.com, or @vtext.com  (those two domains are AT&T and verizon)